# jquery validation plugin & colorbox resize

Tags: jquery, validation, colorbox

I am using the following Jquery validation plugin inside a colorbox. What I am trying to do is fire off `$(this).colorbox.resize();` when the "input" line gets its class modified.

Iv tried to add the resize code in a few spots and its almost working. I just cant seem to add the function where it counts because its still poping scroll bars when the class "error" or "valid" is added or removed but if you click outside of the forms input field the colorbox resize function that I added works.

So, my goal and question is, where do I need to add my colorbox resize so that it fires when the class "error" or "valid" is applied to the input field in my form.

Any help is thanked in advance.

jQuery validation plug-in 1.5.5 was to large to copy here so I put it on Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZHScy/

Comment: Take a look at [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/). It might be helpful since it's fully responsive so I'll adapt to any container you put it in, such as a modal box.

Comment: The validation I have works fine, its just that I put the form inside a colorbox jquery plugin that needs to just resize itself to take into account the new overall height since the lable pops when the filed is no longer valid.

Comment: I could css hack it by floating the label eliment so it doesnt matter but I would like to see if I could get the resize function to fire at the right time. Right now it fires but only after the user clicks outside of the input field or keeps tying and the form rechecks itself for validation

Comment: What I was trying to say is that what you're trying to do is more complicated than it seems. I went through similar trouble when creating the plugin I mentioned above.

Comment: Plus, there are a lot of things to take into account since you're using different plugins and custom code. I doubt you'll find a solution for such a particular case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in my case I don't do any resize. I just let the errors to be overflown

```
$("#My_Form").colorbox();

$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    $("#cboxContent, #cboxOverlay, ,#cboxWrapper, #colorbox").css('overflow', 'visible');

});
```

[image]

FYI, it works in IE, FF, Chrome ...

Answer (score 0):

We need to append an action when we got success for a validation.

Please append the following code.

```
success: function(label) 
{
 $.colorbox.resize();
}
```